# A series with the recursive formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion

> A sequence $\lbrace a_{n}\rbrace_{n\geq 0}$ is constructed by choosing
>   a value of $a_{n}$, and then the following elements are determined
>   from the equation $a_{n}=2-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. Let the
>   power series be given $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}$.
>
> a) Choose $a_{0}=4/3$. Show by induction that $a_{n}$ is constant, and
>   determine the interval of convergence and the sum function of the
>   power series.

**My answer**: First I see that $a_{1}=4/3$ so there must be $a_{n}=4/3$ for all $n\geq 1$. For $n=1$ the statement is clearly true. Assume that the statement is true for $n=m$. For $n=m+1$ we have $a_{m+1}=2-(1/2)a_{m}=2-(1/2)a_{n}=a_{n}$, so the statement for $n=m+1$ is true. We have shown that it is constant.

We have the power series $\sum_{n\geq 0}(4/3)x^{n}$ which is a geometric series that converges if $x\in (-1,1)$ with sum $(4/3)(1-x)^{-1}$.

> b) Choose $a_{0}=2/3$. Show by induction that it holds $2/3\leq a_{n}\leq 5/3$ for all $n$, and use it to determine the radius of
>   convergence of the power series.

**My answer**: 
First, we see that $$\frac{2}{3}\leq a_{n}\leq \frac{5}{3}\iff \frac{2}{3}\leq 2-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}\leq \frac{5}{3}\iff \frac{2}{3}\leq a_{n-1}\leq \frac{8}{3}$$ for all $n\geq 1$. Let $a_{0}=\frac{2}{3}$. We will start showing that $\frac{2}{3}\leq a_{n}$ by induction. The statement is true for $n=1$, since $\frac{2}{3}\leq a_{1}=2-\frac{1}{2}a_{0}$. Assuming $n=m$ to be true and for $n=m+1$, we have
$$\frac{2}{3}\leq a_{m+1}=2-\frac{1}{2}a_{m}=2-\frac{1}{2}a_{n}=2-\frac{1}{2}\left [ 2-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1} \right ]=1+\frac{1}{4}a_{n-1}\leq 1+\frac{1}{4}\frac{8}{3}=\frac{5}{3}$$
which is true. We will now show that $a_{n}\leq \frac{5}{3}$. The statement $n=1$ is clear. Assuming $n=m$ to be true and for $n=m+1$ we have 
$$-\frac{5}{3}\geq -a_{m+1}=-\left [ 2-\frac{1}{2}a_{m} \right ]=\dots=-\left [ 1+\frac{1}{4}a_{n-1} \right ]\geq -\frac{5}{3}.$$
Since it's true for $n=m+1$, we conclude that the hypothesis is true for all $n\geq 1$ by induction.

Since $\frac{2/3}{5/3}\leq \left | \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \right |\leq \frac{5/3}{2/3}$, so the convergence of radius is $r=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left | \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} \right |= \frac{5}{2}$.

How are my answers so far?

Comment: Let $c = \frac{2}{3}$ and $d = \frac{5}{3}$. Since $0 < c \leq |a_n| \leq d$ for all $n$, it follows that $c^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq d^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for all $n$, so $\lim_n |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$. Hence $R = 1$...

Comment: @Shalop Thanks. What exactly is the difference between the formulas we both have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$A(x)
=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}
$.
Since
$a_{n}=2-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}$,

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}\\
&=a_0+\sum_{n\geq 1}a_{n}x^{n}\\
&=a_0+\sum_{n\geq 1}(2-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1})x^{n}\\
&=a_0+\sum_{n\geq 1}2x^n-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}a_{n-1}x^{n}\\
&=a_0+\frac{2x}{1-x}-\frac{x}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{2x+a_0-xa_0}{1-x}-\frac{x}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}\\
&=\frac{x(2-a_0)+a_0}{1-x}-\frac{x}{2}A(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$A(x)(1+\frac{x}{2})
=\frac{x(2-a_0)+a_0}{1-x}
$
or
$A(x)
=\frac{x(2-a_0)+a_0}{1-x}\frac{2}{2+x}
$.

In general,
the radius of convergence
is $2$
(from the $x+2$).
However,
if
$a_0 = 2(2-a_0)$,
so $a_0 = \frac43$,
$A(x)
=\frac{2(\frac43+\frac23 x)}{(1-x)(2+x)}
=\frac{\frac43(2+ x)}{(1-x)(2+x)}
=\frac{4/3}{1-x}
$,
the radius of convergence is $1$.

Note that
we can never cancel out
the $1-x$ in the denominator,
because this would require that
$a_0 = -(2-a_0)
=-2+a_0$,
which is impossible.

Comment: I don't really see how you reached the result of the radius of convergence. Why can't we use the general formula, $r=\rho^{-1}$, where $\rho=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |$? Could you please evaluate my answers in the post?

Comment: But you haven't computed the limit. What you have computed is bounds for $|a_n/a_{n+1}|$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n$ can't be constant.
If it were,
and was equal to $c$,
then
$c = 2-\frac{c}{n}$
or
$c(1+\frac1{n}) = 2$
which is impossible.

Comment: You are right. I have corrected my post. There should be $(1/2)$ instead of $(1/n)$.