# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider a series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}$ where $a_{0}=2/3$ and $a_{n}=2-(1/2)a_{n-1}$ for all $n$. It is assumed that $2/3\leq a_{n}\leq 5/3$ for all $n\geq 1$. My problem is about determining its radius of convergence.

It is a kind of duplicate of my earlier [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283003/a-series-with-the-recursive-formula/). The only difference is that I want to know why I couldn't answer the way I want to according to a theorem of my lecturer,

> Let $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_{n}x^{n}$ be a power series, and assume that
>   $\rho=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |$ exists
>   in $[0,\infty]$. Then the radius of convergence of it is
>   $\rho^{-1}\in [0,\infty]$.

Here goes my thought: Since $a_{n}$ is positive for all $n$, so
$$\left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{2-(1/2)a_{n}}{a_{n}}=\frac{2}{a_{n}}-\frac{1}{2}.$$
By the assumption we have
$$
\frac{2}{3}\leq a_{n}\leq \frac{5}{3}\iff \frac{5}{2}\geq \frac{2}{a_{n}}-\frac{1}{2}\geq \frac{10}{7}.
$$
So it means that
$$\frac{10}{7}\leq \left | \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} \right |\leq \frac{5}{2}$$
Hence the radius of convergence must lie in the interval $[2/5,7/10]$. How do I then find a value of it, or am I missing something? I would be really grateful for your help.

**EDIT**: I am convicted about the root test, but I am told to use the **ratio test**. Please avoid answering about the root test.

Comment: Wouldn't the radius just be how far those inequality values are from a central value, i.e. their average?

Comment: Hint: If there exists some finite and positive $c$ and $C$ such that $c\le|a_n|\le C$ for every $n$ then the radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_na_nz^n$ is $1$.

Comment: If you have to use the ratio test (not a good constraint), the easiest thing here would be to show that $a_n \to \frac{4}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$(2/3)^{1/n}\le a_n^{1/n} \le (5/3)^{1/n}.$ Both the left side and right side of this inequality $\to 1.$ Thus $a_n^{1/n}\to 1.$ By the root test, the ROC is $1.$

Comment: I am already aware of it. I only have to use the *ratio test*, not the root test. What would you then do?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use ratio test to find radius of convergence . Now first of all we find limit of sequence as a tends to infinity = 4/3 .Then we use ratio test to get x<1 for series to converge and hence radius of convergence is 1.